# How to customize pom.xml in Spring Tool Suite (STS)

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

all,
    I'm trying to find where the template of pom.xml for Spring Maven project is in STS. I want to customize it because lots of jar releases that the default pom.xml are using is out-of-date.

```
Anyone knows where the template of pom.xml is?
```

Comment: At the moment there is no easy way of changing the template for this yourself. You can hack this, if you want, by changing the template content under the hood in your workspace (the cached data if you used the template at least once), it is located here: .metadata/.sts/simpleprojects.

Comment: But I would also recommend to file an enhancement request at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS to make this easier.